# Difference between closures and scope in javascript

Tags: scope, closures

I am having an extremely hard time understanding why closures need to exist. If you have function (b), that returns a function (b), then doesn't the scope of b already just include a. If there is a reference to the variables in function (a) in function (b), then wouldn't this mean that the garbage collector wouldn't dispose of the variables? If someone could give a detailed explanation on how scope and closure work on a higher level that would be extremely helpful.

I've tried looking for explanations but most explanations have the same basic overview of scope and closures. I am trying to understand how these get implemented from the beginning to the end of the program.